# Looking to validate that certain string is present in a text file, send warning if not

Tags: string, powershell, conditional-statements

I have a process where files containing data are generated in separate locations, saved to a networked location, and merged into a single file.

And the end of the process, I would like to check that all locations are present in that merged file, and notify me if not.

I am having a problem finding a way to identify that a string specific to each location isn't present, to be used in an if statement, but it doesn't seem to be identifying the string correctly?

I have tried :

```
get-childitem -filter *daily.csv.ready \\x.x.x.x\data\* -recurse | where-object {$_ -notin 'D,KPI,KPI,1,'}
```

I know it's probably easier to do nothing if it is present, and perform the warning action if not, but I'm curious if this can be done in the reverse.

Thank you,

Comment: You’re never retrieving the contents of the file to begin with, so you’ll never find or not find what you’re after

Answer (score 0):

As [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) points out, your command does *not* search through the *content* of the files output by the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) command, because what that cmdlet emits are [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) (or, potentially, [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)) instances containing *metadata* about the matching files (directories) rather than their *content*.

In other words: the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) in your [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) command refers to an object *describing* a file rather than its content.

However, you *can* pipe `System.IO.FileInfo` instances to the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet, which indeed searches the input files' *content*:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *daily.csv.ready \\x.x.x.x\data\* -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { $_ | Select-String -Quiet -NotMatch 'D,KPI,KPI,1,' }
```